# How do I test a callback of a React component wrapped in withRouter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to test a React project written in TypeScript. I have a component that is wrapped in a React-Router router, and which looks somewhat like this:

```
import { SomeButton } from './someButton';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';

const SomeButtonWithRouter = withRouter<{buttonCallback: () => void}>(SomeButton);

export class SomePage extends React.Component <RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.someCallback = this.someCallback.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SomeButtonWithRouter buttonCallback={this.someCallback}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // This is the callback I want to  test:
  private someCallback() {
    console.log('This is a callback');
  }
```

Now I'm trying to write a test that calls `someCallback` and then makes some assertions. I've wrapped `SomePage` in a `MemoryRouter` to be able to test it:

```
it('should do something', () => {
  const page = mount(<MemoryRouter><SomePage/></MemoryRouter>);
  const cb = page.find('SomeButton').prop('buttonCallback'); // <-- this is undefined
});
```

As mentioned in the comment, unfortunately the `buttonCallback` prop is undefined when accessed like this. However, when I output `page`, it does say it is defined:

```
<withRouter(SomeButton)
  onVerified={[Function bound ]}
```

and some lines below:

```
<SomeButton
  history={ // ...
  // ...
  onVerified={[Function bound ]}
```

Both `SomeButton` and `withRouter(SomeButton)` don't work as selectors for Enzyme's `find`.

I'm not sure why that's the case; I *am* able to access a callback this way for another child component that is not wrapped in `withRouter`. I'm also not sure whether everything I'm doing is the right way to do them in the first place, so any pointers as to better ways of doing things are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grr... As usual, a night of sleep helped me identify the problem - and it wasn't actually here. In case it helps anyone, I'll detail the mistakes I made.

First, the most useful thing to know: both `const cb = page.find('SomeButton').prop('buttonCallback');` as well as `const cb = page.find('withRouter(SomeButton)').prop('buttonCallback');` should work - although I'd go for the former, as then you don't need to know about the use of the router.

Second, the reason I thought it didn't work was because I was trying to output the result using `toJson(page.find('SomeButton').prop('buttonCallback'))` (using [`enzyme-to-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-to-json)), which will happily convert that function to `undefined`.

And finally, and this is the dumbest thing - I didn't saw an effect from calling the callback because... I didn't actually call it. I merely assigned it `const buttonCallback = page.find...`, but had to follow that up with `buttonCallback()`. Oh, and also: there was a typo in my assertion afterwards.

I know, dumb. Feel free to laugh at me when you come across this issue in six months.